# Android MVP variable getter inside Presenter

Tags: android, android-mvp, presenter

I have a special case in my project that relies on MVP pattern.

The use case is that when clicking a button an contact email should be sent.
The email is created dynamically, a combination from some input fields and some data from repository and string resources.

The flow starts like this:

**Fragment/View**:

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener { presenter.onSendButtonClick(
    emailField.text.toString(),
    questionField.text.toString(),
    getSubjectWithTimeStamp(presenter.getMyObject(), getString(R.string.app_name))
)}

private fun getMailSubjectTimeStamp(object: MyObject? = null, appName: String): String {
    val timeStamp = MAIL_SUBJECT_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.format(Date())
    return if (object != null) {
        getString(
            R.string.help_contactForm_subject_with_data,
            appName,
            object.someInfo,
            timeStamp
        )
    } else {
        getString(
            R.string.help_contactForm_subject,
            appName,
            timeStamp
        )
    }
}
```

**Presenter**:

```
private var lastKnownObject: MyObject? = null

override fun onBound(view: ContactContract.View) {
    super.onBound(view)
    scope.launch {
        // This is fetched from DB behind the scene via the Interactor.
        lastKnownObject = myObjectInteractor.readLastKnownObject()
    }
}

override fun getLastKnownObject(): MyObject? {
    return lastKnownObject
}

override fun onSendButtonClick(userMail: String, questionText: String, subject: String) {
    sendMailAndShowFeedback(userMail, questionText, subject)
}
```

This works, but I'm not very happy with the fact that I need to expose a variable from my presenter and manually access it before triggering the flow with `onSendButtonClick`.
Any other ideas on how to achieve this kind of combination and still have my separation of concerns?

Comment: Create a StringProvider and inject it to the presenter. The string provider implementation will internally use the app context to get strings. Then move the `getMailSubjectTimeStamp` into the presenter keeping view as simple as possible. That way you can easily unit test the presenter logic.

Comment: Thanks @DerekK, that makes sense as it will keep the presenter cleaner (instead of having that getter on it). The downside is that I will add Context aware components in my presenter. 
Will give it a go nonetheless.